# ArcGIS Pro Map Series - prevent overlapping inset map

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

I'm using Map Series in ArcGIS Pro to produce layouts for around 1,000 small area boundaries. The layout includes an inset map in the top right corner showing the location of the small area in the main map at a larger scale. However, in some of the layouts, the inset map overlaps with a part of the small area. Is there an automated method that places the inset map in each layout in the Map Series in an appropriate corner (top right, top left, bottom right or bottom left) to ensure that it doesn't overlap with the small area boundary in the main map?